# How can I use git to provide a word count graph?

Tags: git, graph, wc

I'm writing a long piece of prose and want to use git to track the word count. (Not a graph of commits, which is well documented.)

How can I plot a graph of word count vs time (or word count vs commit)?

Comment: ... because screwdrivers drive nails so well... There are much better tools out there for this job. `perl` and/or `python` come to mind...

Comment: @johntait I think you probably understood that git would fetch the history and some external tool, not git itself, would be better to do the actual word counting - am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, git doesn't have a feature for word counting, let alone drawing graphs of word counts. However, you can combine git and other tools to do that.

For example, this will output word counts for each commit that changed `file.txt` file:

```
git rev-list HEAD -- file.txt |
    while read c; do git show "$c:file.txt" | wc -w; done
```

And this will output the same along with commit timestamps:

```
git rev-list --timestamp HEAD -- file.txt |
    while read t c; do echo -n "$t "; git show "$c:file.txt" | wc -w; done
```

You can feed this output to gnuplot, or paste it into openofice.org Calc to plot a graph.